# How to sample binary data to get a normal distribution of the sum of the rows

Tags: r, simulation, normal-distribution

I want to create 4 binary variables with a sample of 300 (assume I may want to increase 4 to 10 variables). But when I sum by rows I want to get a normal distribution for the sum column. Can we do it in R? Here is a random sample to demonstrate.

```
  m1    m2  m3  m4  sum
    1   1   0   1   3
    1   1   0   1   3
    1   0   0   0   1
    0   1   0   0   1
    0   0   1   0   1
    0   1   1   0   2
    1   0   1   1   3
    0   0   1   1   2
    0   0   1   0   1
    1   0   0   1   2
    1   0   0   0   1
    1   0   0   0   1
    1   0   1   1   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you were asking for:

```
data <- data.frame(m1=numeric(),m2=numeric(),m3=numeric(),m4=numeric())
data[1:300,1] <- sample(0:1,300,replace = TRUE)
data[1:300,2] <- sample(0:1,300,replace = TRUE)
data[1:300,3] <- sample(0:1,300,replace = TRUE)
data[1:300,4] <- sample(0:1,300,replace = TRUE)
data$sum <- data[,1] + data[,2] + data[,3] + data[,4]
```

`plot(density(data$sum,bw = 2))`[image]
**EDIT**
distribution:
`plot(table(data$sum))`[image]

Comment: That's not showing the distribution of the sum, that's showing the **smoothed density** of the sum (kernel density estimate) (note that the plot you're showing ranges from -5 to 10, the range of the outcome is only from 0 to 4 ...). I'm afraid the OP will be led astray by this. (It may be that a Binomial(N=4,p=0.5) response is fine for what they want to do, but it may not ... it's hard to tell.)  Can you please show the results of `plot(table(data$sum))` for clarity/contrast?

Comment: Thanks. If that's actually good enough for the OP ...

Answer (score 1):

Not only can't you do it in R, I don't think it's possible.

- The distribution of the sum will be a discrete variable with possible outcomes {0,1,2,3,4}. There's no way this can be very close to a Normal distribution, which is continuous/real-valued.
- In the simplest case (the columns are independent with equal means), the result will be binomial. One rule of thumb for "the Normal approximation to the binomial distribution is adequate" is `n*p*(1-p)>5`; in this case since `n=4`, the best you can do (with `p=0.5`) is `n*p*(1-p)=1`.  Increasing to 10 will get you up to a best-case scenario of `n*p*(1-p)=2.5` (in general `n/4` ...), still not very good.
- It may be possible to relax the assumptions of independence and equi-probability across the rows and still get a binomial (you could ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)), but in any case I don't know that any deviations from binomiality that you get due to correlation and variation across rows will actually make the Normal approximation better ... For example, you could set the samples up so that `{P(0)=P(3)=0; P(2)=P(4)=0.5}` (which is an impossible PDF for a binomial), but that's not helping.

Comment: Thank you, why  I cannot assume the sum can be treated like we do in likert scales?

Comment: you could fit an ordinal model to these simulated data.  That's quite different from summing 4-10 binary variables and ending up with a Normally distributed outcome.

Comment: In achievement tests ( based on 0 and 1) and you always calculate the performance and then calculate mean...Sorry,  point 2 and three do not help

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. This is probably a better question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), because the "what should I do?" question looks harder/more fundamental than the "how do I do <whatever I decide> in R?" question. In any case, the answer to your question **as stated** is "you can't". If you want to broaden your question and give more context about your more general goal, feel free to edit your question (or delete this and re-post on CV).